# Writing JavaScript in ASP classic

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

Is it possible (and how if so) to write JavaScript code directly into an ASP classic file?

I want to create validation functions inside an ASP classic file.

Comment: Of course.  Did you try?  You can include JavaScript in the output just like any other client-side code (such as HTML and CSS).  The server-side technology used makes no difference.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use client side JS as you would in a flat html file or do you mean that you want to use it as your server side scripting language instead of VBScript?  In either case the answer is yes

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ASP is a technology, NOT a language. You can write your ASP pages in any language which is registered as a Scripting Engine. So you can use VBScript, Javascript, Perl, ... if there is a scripting engine registered in your server, you can use it.

How? Like this!

```
<%@ Language= "Javascript" %> 
<% 
  var message = 'This is my message: ';
  for (var i = 0, endI = 10 ; i < endI ; i++){ 
      Response.Write( message + ' ' + i + '<br>' ) ;
  };
%>
```

Comment: Can I jump between VBscript and JavaScript and how?

Comment: You SHOULD NOT use the two (or more) at the same time in the same page. Lot of reasons for a comment. Try and you will see. BUT, if you keep each page with only one language, you can use Server.Execute or Server.Transfer to organize execution. AND what you SHOULD do with multiple languages is encapsulate code in .WSC (windows script components).

Comment: @Zephram from a JS page, or VB page, you can include a `<script runat="server" language="..." src="..."></script>` that will load any language installed for the scripting runtime (VBScript and JScript by default, but there are/were other options) ... the only big issue in JScript is COM based collections are awkward to deal with.