# ASPJson and Mandrill API

Tags: json, api, asp-classic

I am using the aspJSON Class:
http://www.aspjson.com/

To try and write some simple JSON to use for a basic test on the Mandrill email API:
https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=send

I wrote a simple bit of JSON using the "write.asp" example from the aspJSON page via this basic test:

```
<!--#include file="aspJSON.asp" -->
<%
Set oJSON = New aspJSON

'Write single value
oJSON.data("familyName") = "Smith"

'Make collection
Set oJSON.data("familyMembers") = oJSON.Collection()

'Add instances to collection
Set newitem = oJSON.AddToCollection(oJSON.data("familyMembers"))
newitem.add "firstName", "John"
newitem.add "age", 41
newitem.add "gender", "Male"

Set newitem = oJSON.AddToCollection(oJSON.data("familyMembers"))
newitem.add "firstName", "Suzan"
newitem.add "age", 38
newitem.add "gender", "Female"

Set newitem = oJSON.AddToCollection(oJSON.data("familyMembers"))
newitem.add "firstName", "John Jr."
newitem.add "age", 11
newitem.add "gender", "Male"

'Return the object
Response.Write oJSON.JSONoutput()
%>
```

That works for quite a "flat" JSON structure which like this:

```
{
  "familyName": "Smith",
  "familyMembers":
  [
    {
      "firstName": "John",
      "age": 41,
      "gender": "Male"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Suzan",
      "age": 38,
      "gender": "Female"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "John Jr.",
      "age": 11,
      "gender": "Male"
    }
  ]
}
```

But what I'm struggling with is how to write a JSON string like the one shown in the Madrill docs, where the nesting is deeper than shown on the aspJSON example.

For example, this is an extract for the Mandrill JSON string:

```
{
    "key": "example key",
    "message": {
        "html": "<p>Example HTML content</p>",
        "text": "Example text content",
        "subject": "example subject",
        "from_email": "message.from_email@example.com",
        "from_name": "Example Name",
        "to": [
            {
                "email": "recipient.email@example.com",
                "name": "Recipient Name",
                "type": "to"
            }
        ],
        "headers": {
            "Reply-To": "message.reply@example.com"
        },
    "async": false,
    "ip_pool": "Main Pool",
    "send_at": "example send_at"
}
```

As you can see for the "to" and "headers" section, the level of nesting is deeper than on the aspJSON example.

I tried this in my ASP code:

```
<!--#include file="aspJSON.asp" -->
<%
Set oJSON = New aspJSON

'Write single value
oJSON.data("key") = "MY_KEY"

'Make collection
Set oJSON.data("message") = oJSON.Collection()

'Add instances to collection
Set newitem = oJSON.AddToCollection(oJSON.data("message"))
newitem.add "text", "Hello world!"
newitem.add "subject", "Test Subject"
newitem.add "from_email", "me@you.com"
newitem.add "from_name", "Bob Holnas"

Set newitem = oJSON.AddToCollection(oJSON.data("to"))
newitem.add "email", "him@her.com"
newitem.add "name", "Arthur Smith"
newitem.add "type", "to"

Set newitem = oJSON.AddToCollection(oJSON.data("headers"))
newitem.add "Reply-To", "us@them.com"

'Return the object
Response.Write oJSON.JSONoutput()
%>
```

But got this error:

```
AddToCollection Error error '800a0001'
Not a collection.
/websites/aspJSON/aspJSON.asp, line 77
```

I have locally hosted the data from "aspJSON.asp" on my site here:
http://jimpix.co.uk/aspJSON.txt

As it is not available via the aspJSON site.

Any advice would be very much appreciated, as I am really stuck!

Thanks

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that it's easier to use Jscript as your server side scripting language when dealing with JSON rather than use any of vbs libraries I've seen - and I say that as someone who generally hates using js.

Comment: Hi John - thanks for your reply. Is one advantage of using ASP that I don't have to make my public Madrill API key public? If I used Javascript, wouldn't I have to put the key in the JavaScript file? Thanks

Comment: No, I mean use js server side - inside your <% %> delimiters.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704736/writing-javascript-in-asp-classic

Answer (score 4):

First let me say I've never used this class before.
After studying the class, I wrote an example and tried to be helpful in the comments.
Hope it helps.

```vb
<!--#include file="aspJSON.asp" -->
<%
Set oJSON = New aspJSON

With oJSON.data
    .Add "key", "MY_KEY"
    .Add "message", oJSON.Collection()
    With oJSON.data("message")
        .Add "text", "Hello world!"
        .Add "subject", "Test Subject"
        .Add "from_email", "me@you.com"
        .Add "from_name", "Bob Holnas"
        .Add "to", oJSON.Collection()
        With .Item("to")
            'To obtain a collection will be considered an array for output, specify integer keys instead of string
            .Add 0, oJSON.Collection() 'first index is a collection
            With .Item(0) 'add key-value pairs to first index of the collection
                .Add "email", "him@her.com"
                .Add "name", "Arthur Smith"
                .Add "type", "to"
            End With
        End With
        .Add "headers", oJSON.Collection()
        With .Item("headers")
            .Add "Reply-To", "us@them.com"
        End With
    End With
    '.Add "async", false
    '.Add "ip_pool", "Main Pool"
    '.Add "send_at", "example send_at"
End With    

Response.Write oJSON.JSONoutput()
%>
```

Given output:

```vb
{
    "key": "MY_KEY",
    "message": {
        "text": "Hello world!",
        "subject": "Test Subject",
        "from_email": "me@you.com",
        "from_name": "Bob Holnas",
        "to": [
            {
                "email": "him@her.com",
                "name": "Arthur Smith",
                "type": "to"
            }
        ],
        "headers": {
            "Reply-To": "us@them.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi - that is really so extremely helpful, thank you so much for taking the time to do that, I really appreciate it :-) Thank you!