# JavaScript vs Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, web

I am new in the web-dev. I read both JS and Ajax but was confused, which one is better in terms of simplicity and performance?

We have lot of JS frameworks but do we have same in the Ajax?

Comment: Javascript is a language, AJAX is technique for communicating from a browser to the server - which uses Asyncronous Javascript And XML.  They are not directly comparable.

Comment: ajax = asynchronous javaScript and XML :-)

Comment: Javascript is a programming language and Ajax is just for async communication to the server.

Comment: @JamesGaunt: It should be called AJAJ nowadays :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is a client-side script, used to control a web page at the client side once it has downloaded. The validations in case of JavaScript will be handled particularly on client’s browser and no server side requests will be handled.

AJAX allows JavaScript to communicate with the remote script and receive the response from the server, without the need to reload the entire page. JavaScript is the base on which Ajax works.

Comment: "JavaScript is a client-side script" — http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Uses_outside_web_pages / http://nodejs.org/ / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704736/writing-javascript-in-asp-classic

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript is a programming language.

Ajax is a buzzword that has come to mean the act of using JavaScript to make an HTTP request from a browser without leaving the page. (Originally the term was specific to requesting XML, occasionally people use it to discuss using other languages (like Flash) to fetch data from a page.)

They aren't alternatives to each other. Comparing them is like comparing potatoes to eating.