# call .js function in classic ASP page

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

call .js function in separate classic asp page - not working

common.js file - separate file path

file path ----- common\javascript\common.js

```
function jsEnableBHIRemappingAttributes() { 
   if (enableBHIattributes != null) {
       var oOldFormat = enableBHIattributes.selectSingleNode("/return/data/EnableBHIRemappingAttributes");
       if (oOldFormat != null && oOldFormat.text.toLowerCase() == "y") {
           return true;
       }
       else {
           return false;
       }
   }
}
```

Classic page...

AccountsDetail.asp
file path ----- Accounts\AccountsDetail.asp

Added js file in the

```
<head>
<script language="Javascript" src="../common/javascript/common.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
ElseIf (sApplCode = "CLOAN") Then
    Dim isBHIAttributesEnabled: isBHIAttributesEnabled = jsEnableBHIRemappingAttributes()
       
    If (isBHIAttributesEnabled = True) Then
       sStylesheetFile = "commercialLoansBHI.xsl"
    Else
        sStylesheetFile = "commercialLoans.xsl"
    End

</body>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing JavaScript in ASP classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704736/writing-javascript-in-asp-classic)

Comment: ASP is executed on the server, whereas you are including that javascript for use in the browser. The server will have no ability to reference the script

Answer (score 0):

**CLIFFNOTES:**  You forgot the `<script></script>` tags.

If you want to use JavaScript in ASP Classic, make sure its done outside of the `<% %>` tags of course.  And the code its self needs to be inside of script tags:

Example:

```
<body>
<% some asp code %>
<script> ..JavaScript.. </script>
<% more asp code %>
</body>
```

Answer:

```
<script>
ElseIf (sApplCode = "CLOAN") Then
Dim isBHIAttributesEnabled: isBHIAttributesEnabled = jsEnableBHIRemappingAttributes()
   
If (isBHIAttributesEnabled = True) Then
   sStylesheetFile = "commercialLoansBHI.xsl"
Else
    sStylesheetFile = "commercialLoans.xsl"
End
</script>
```

Although it's not entirely true, you can, against advisement however, use `Response.Write` to make ASP Classic write JavaScript or HTML or what not like this:

```
Response.Write("<script> javascript </script>")
```

However, you need to make sure that if you use `(` to close it with the other `)`, and often times they aren't needed but helps visually with formatting the code sometimes.

And *importantly*, if the JavaScript code uses `"` double quotes in it, replace them with `'` single quotes in between the `"` double quotes of the `Response.Write` and you could technically put JavaScript inside of the `<% %>` tags if you want to be a contrarian.

Comment: common.js file - separate file path @Jon P
at the top of OP's post, he wants to call the .js file from his ASP Classic script, which is not a problem, as long as you put the <script> and </script> tags between the code.

Comment: Alas, after digging for citations I found perhaps reason to mark this as a dupe.  Perhaps my example will still be useful, but here is that citation:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704736/writing-javascript-in-asp-classic/19707779#19707779

Comment: Yeah that is neat and all, but I said JavaScript in my posts .. you were the first one to just use the word java .. so what are you trying to do here XD.

Comment: Yeah and count how many times I said Javascript before that, and how quickly the edit was when I added that whole extra section at the bottom to help people, in which you found the mistype.  And instead of clicking "edit" and fixing the obvious typo you had to make a comment about it.  But its fixed, thanks.

Comment: You could edit it and in the comment line if you weren't sure, or could point out that information there.  But clearly if I am passing on information about JavaScript and ASP Classic, its not Java .. but its fine, have a good one.

Comment: Cleaned out the "Java" comments as you have now fixed that. There is however the  bigger problem that you can't mix javascript and vbscript on the same line. In the line `Dim isBHIAttributesEnabled: isBHIAttributesEnabled = jsEnableBHIRemappingAttributes()` the method `jsEnableBHIRemappingAttributes()` is javascript and can not be executed by vbscript. If it has any references to the DOM it won't work. And while you can write clasic ASP with javascript it isn't advisable to mix them on the same page, and you can't just mix and match in a given code block.

Comment: Yes, its best to separate them just for visual reasons alone, a screen filled with Response.Write gets cluttered quickly.  But yes, as I mentioned, to overcome this, you break out of the <% %> blocks to the standard HMTL segments, and can put your Javascript code between the <script></script> tags.

Comment: Yes, thats fine when the javascript is executing in the browser, but the OP is trying to call a javascript function (`jsEnableBHIRemappingAttributes()`) and assign the result to a VBScript variable (`Dim isBHIAttributesEnabled`) on the server, you can't **execute** different languages within the same `<script>`  block. The whole line `Dim isBHIAttributesEnabled: isBHIAttributesEnabled = jsEnableBHIRemappingAttributes()` will simply not work.

Comment: Apologies.... meant `script` block , not the tag version as it is possilbe to write classic as with javascript using `<%@ language="javascript"%>` that would be the only viable here option **IF** `jsEnableBHIRemappingAttributes()` has no DOM references.

Comment: OK I might be wrong on this : http://phrogz.net/tmp/serversidejsandvb.html , but it wil require juggling of `<% language= runat=server %>` or `<script language="" runat=server>`  tags and the javascript code will need to wrapped to run on the server.

Comment: Jon, you are onto something, Dim is VB .. well spotted.  You don't need to set the language or run at server, but you can if you like.  At least I always got it to work without, but you can specify , and might want to in case you have more than one type of language going on beyond these.  Just adding the script tags, plus removing the VB code mixed in should fix it up.  But .. I'm starting to wonder Jon .. is Dinesh coming back .. is this all for not?